# Single quote sent by form inside string is different server side

Tags: php, string, special-characters, quote

I am trying to compare strings sent from PHP form (using strcasecmp()). But there is a string with single quote, which breaks the comparison result.

`'`
is returning `´`

So comparison fails.
How to deal with this?
Thanks

Comment: There's nothing in PHP that does that automatically. It sounds like the user has "Smart Quotes" enabled in their browser.

Comment: Ok,but is there any way to fix this? because I have no control on users browsers.

Comment: You can use `str_replace()` to replace characters like that before comparing.

Comment: But that isn't even a smart quote, those are usually curly. I think the user is just typing the wrong type of quote.